# Having trouble with this: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: php, image, parameters, fatal-error, imgur

This is my code, it doesn't like the last line where I call a method from the header file. It claims invalid parameter number even though the method I'm calling takes the same amount of arguments. I don't understand the parameter was not defined part since $params is defined right before the call, and $query is passed a value from my other file, should I check if it's set? Here's my call to the uploadImage method with the value of $query:

Image::uploadImage('postimg', "UPDATE dry_posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid'=>$postid));

This file is supposed to upload images from a form in a another file onto imgur.

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

    class Image
    {
        public static function uploadImage($formname,$query,$params)
        {

            $formname = "";
            $response = "";
            $image = "";

            if(file_exists($formname))
            {
                $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$formname]['tmp_name']));
            }
            $options = array('http'=>array(
                'method'=>"POST",
                'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer 8cd9d1bb71401737dc720f9381d8e9763f580af6\n".
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'content'=>$image
            ));

            $context = stream_context_create($options);
            $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
            if ($_FILES[$formname]['size'] > 10240000) {
                die('Image too big, must be 10MB or less!');
            }
            if(file_exists($formname))
            {
                $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);

            }
            $response = json_decode($response);

            $preparams = array($formname=>$response->data->link);
            $params = $preparams + $params;

            connect::query($query,$params);


        }



    }



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the array `array(':postid'=>$postid)`, you also need to pass the param `postimg` which you have used in the query.
Something like `array(':postid'=>$postid, ':postimg'=>$postimg)`

Comment: ok, now it's giving me this:  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: I tried putting $postimg to the parameter list on uploadImage but it didn't like that

Comment: Why are you merging the `$params` array here: `$params = $preparams + $params;` ?

Comment: so the url from the query will be prepended

Comment: I've tried just using one but the error is still there

Comment: Using just one how?

Comment: nvm now I've changed how I passed in params to this : array(':postid'=>$postid), array(':postimg'=>$postimg)

Comment: now I'm getting this: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Comment: btw I tried using just one array like this :                                          $params=array($formname=>$response->data->link)+array(':postid'=>$postid)+array(':postimg'=>$postimg);

Comment: I don't think you need the $formName array in the above statement

Comment: I've changed it to this: $params=array($response->data->link)+array(':post‌​id'=>$postid).array(':postimg'=>$postimg‌​);   and got rid of the error but now I have this warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given,  as well as a few notices and my images still won't post

Comment: What I meant was to remove the whole array($formname=>$response->data->link)+ portion from the code

Comment: oh ok now that I have this : $params=array(':post‌​id'=>$postid)+array(':postimg'=>$postimg‌​);    I'm getting the original error again , invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the $formName array in the above statement

Comment: oh ok now that I have this : $params=array(':post‌​id'=>$postid)+array(':postimg'=>$posti‌​mg‌​); I'm getting the original error again , invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Try removing the postimg array as well from the above statement